# Is there a terminal app that can record commands?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications

Coming from windows using Mobaxterm I really miss the ability to record a "macro" for certain commands and able to to play back on the terminal.  Whats more Mobaexterm was also able to save ssh session so that all the login info like address are saved?  My question is there something similar for Macs?  thank you.

Comment: This is rather broad right now. You can use shell scripts to collect shell commands you want to rerun, and OpenSSH configurations to store login details. What exactly do you want your question focus on (you can easily ask the other part in a separate question)? If you're not fully sure, can you please add an example each of both cases and we take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Terminal.app (the default macOS terminal application) [can be scripted](https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/terminal/trml1003/mac) using AppleScript but a better option may be [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/), which can be [scripted](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html) using Python (AppleScript is also supported but it's deprecated).

If you'd like to save ssh sessions your most portable option is to use the OpenSSH [client configuration file](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) (typically named `~/.ssh/config`). Using it you can configure per connection settings like key, username, etc.